# Add button or action to User layout in both Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience mode

Tags: lightning-experience, page-layout, button, quickaction, salesforce-classic

I need to add button (or action button, it doesn't really matter) to both Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience mode on User layout but looks like [it is not possible to add buttons to user layout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=defining_custom_links.htm&type=5)

> Custom buttons aren’t available on the User object or custom home pages.

Can I add some action to Lightning Experience at least? I do have Highlights panel on User Records Page in Lightning, but looks like there is no section "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions" in User Profile Layout or do I miss anything????

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found so far is the following.

Implementing custom component `Buttons` which implements `flexipage:availableForRecordHome` and `force:hasRecordId` interfaces

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="XXXX" onclick="{! c.action }"/>
</aura:component>
```

and contains one or several buttons.

In the lightning controller I can define the action for button click event.

```
({
    action : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert('x');
    }
})
```

Then I can put that component to User Records Page just beneath the Highlights Panel.
[image]

and thus having it on user layout in Lightning Experience interface.

For Salesforce Classic interface I have to create Lightning Out application

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:Buttons"/>
</aura:application>
```

Then Visualforce page which will use Lightning Out Application and Lightning Component

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="User" >

    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:ButtonsOut", function() {
            // Write a function that creates the component on the page
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:Buttons",
          {},
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
          });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>

</apex:page>
```

Then I have to modify layout and put page to the top available section of the User Layout.

Unfortunately, I can't put it above the Standards Fields section. Nor by point and click configuration neither by layout XML ANT Deployment Tool hacking.

[image]